# Unable to run python file from terminal

Tags: command-line, python

I am not able to run this Python file from terminal.

I have added the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at start of the file.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? How can I run this file from terminal?

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfOdn.jpg I guess, this might be helpful.

Comment: is it executable ?

Comment: shouldn't the shebang be `/usr/bin/python`, and not `/usr/bin/env python`?

Comment: also, can you simply run `python aaa.py` or already simply `python`?

Comment: Show what `which python` and `which env` says, and add the first lines of your `aaa.py` file.

Comment: Yes, it is executable. The green font color means the file is executable.
@don.joey: python aaa.py works but I want to now why this way it is not working.

This file was running the same way few days back but now its not. what could be the reason?

Comment: For the sake of argument, what happens if you explicitly run `python aaa.py`?

Comment: @Potato_head please add the output of `which python` --- are you sure you have it in your PATH?

Comment: command : python aaa.py works just fine.
command : ./aaa.py gives error : No such file or directory.
Why? @Rmano : https://i.imgur.com/To85TPD.jpg  Can you please explain, what you mean by "are you sure you have it in your PATH"?

Comment: Look at your last screenshot: you have an invisible char `^M` after the `python` in the shebang line. This is probably a remnant of having edited the file on a non-Unix machine (typically, Windows). Delete that char and it will work --- if you had cut and pasted that error in the question, without screenshots, you have had the answer instantly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The screenshot below show the problem: you have an invisible char `^M` after the python in the shebang line. This is probably a remnant of having [edited the file on a non-Unix machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508923/find-and-remove-dos-line-endings-on-ubuntu) (typically, Windows); so the interpreter looked for is `python^M` which is not found.

If you haven't edited this file on a alien os, maybe it's a problem with the line-ending setting on your editor. Anyway, rewriting the shebang line in a sane editor should fix the thing up.

[image]

Comment: I have faced this problem earlier. `^M` was visible only in terminal editors like `nano` and not in graphical editors like gedit or sublime text. Had to edit the file in nano to remove all the `^M` characters from the file. It worked fine thereafter.

Comment: @Aditya: no need to do that manually. Sublime for example lets you see and change line endings with 2 clicks, you just need to set `"show_line_endings": true` in the preferences.

Comment: @LeartS: Yes. It's set to `false` by default. But good to know if I encounter it again in future :)

Answer (score 4):

Your file has [Windows line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations), which unix shells [don't like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems).

Just convert them to Unix file endings using `dos2unix aaa.py` (you may need to install `dos2unix`, which is a very light [200kB] but useful software) and you should be fine.

---

Different line endings representations are a common source of "strange" problems. You can check line endings with `file <yourfile>` if it says something like:

```
<yourfile>: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

It means it has Windows line endings and you should [convert them to unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities), using `dos2unix`, the vim command `:set ff=unix` or your favourite text editor if it has the feature (many do).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hFkElwK.png I think, I did got rid of the line ending problem. but its still giving me the same output. 
:No such file or directory.   
file aaa.py gives output aaa.py, Python script, ASCII text executable.

Comment: It does not give you the same output: before it was `: no such file or directory` now it is `usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`  
Did you change the shebang in the meantime, maybe from `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!usr/bin/python`? If you did, that is now the problem. Go back to the original one.

Comment: Yes, I used #!usr/bin/python instead of #!usr/bin/env python. Reverting it did't help.

Comment: They are both wrong, a leading slash is missing. A leading slash indicates an absolute uri, without it is relative to the current directory and you don't have a `usr/bin/python` (nor `env`) in the current directory.

The correct shebang is: `#!/usr/bin/env python`.